# Is srsName of "EPSG:4326" spec compliant in GML 3.1 / 3.2?

Tags: gml, ogc, specification

I sometimes see `srsName="EPSG:4326"` in GML documents (e.g. https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGML.html, although my particular source is not public). The intent (except perhaps for axis order that isn't important here) is clear, and probably interoperable across various systems, but I wonder if that is actually specification compliant.

I've looked at the [OGC Naming Authority](http://www.opengeospatial.org/ogcna) and [OGC URN policy](http://www.opengeospatial.org/ogcUrnPolicy), and they use the `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:\d{4,5}` form (i.e. it would be `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326`).

The GML Point Profile (OGC 05-029r4) uses `srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.6:4326"` in examples, and requires that to be "well known". I don't see anything in there that actually excludes any particular `srsName` though.

Is the `srsName="EPSG:abcd"` form (in particular, `srsName="EPSG:4326"`) specification compliant for a GML 3.1 or 3.2 element (in particular, for Point Profile)?

Comment: Rejected the add of the postgis tag - the question is not about postgis (or any other implementation), but rather about the spec.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `srsName="EPSG:abcd"` is GML-3 compliant but only in an application context where `EPSG:abcd` points to a CRS definition. As of 2013, OGC best practice ([documented here](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=53819)) is to use http URIs of the form http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326.

The GML-3.0.0 spec ([OCG 02-023r4](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=7174)) section v.2, page xiv states aliasing CRSs is kosher:

> in GML we have found it convenient for an identified object to be able
>   to carry several “names” – i.e. labels either assigned by external
>   authorities or commonly used for an object. These may be distinguished
>   from each other by noting the “codeSpace” for a name, which allows a consumer of the information to select the appropriate name for them to use.

The GML-3.2.1 spec ([OGC 03-105r1](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=4700)) section 10.1.3.2, page 56 says :

> In general the attribute srsName [of type="anyURI"] points to a CRS
>   instance of gml:AbstractCoordinateReferenceSystem (see 12.2.3). For
>   well-known references it is not required that the CRS description
>   exists at the location the URI points to.

While there's no explicit definition of "well-known" within the GML-3 spec, using [OGC 05-029r4](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=11606) (section 4, page 8)'s definition of "well-known" as "not requiring resolution," so long as an application can internally identify a CRS from an URI , you might say the CRS is "well-known."  Thus, using GML-3.1 & 3.2's somewhat complicated system of pointing to CRSs by name can be interpreted as the CRSs being well-known, and so `EPSG:abcd` is perfectly valid.  If you want to explore the exact methods with which GML points to a CRS via an srsName, see referenceSystems.xsd in http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.0/base/ and http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/ .

It is worth noting that after the publication of the white paper "OGC Identifiers-the Case for HTTP URIs" ([OGC 10-124r1](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=39467)) came out in 2010, OGC specification documents more or less transitioned to that standard.

Comment: Can you say why you think "EPSG:####" is a URN? From https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8141#section-2 it would have to start with `urn:` as the registered URI scheme, at least. Also, I don't get what you think this is do with geoserver (which I am fairly familiar with).

Comment: Yep, my mistake, EPSG:#### is not an URN.  I gave the geoserver WFS docs since both it gives some examples of valid srsName formats, but you're right, it's off-topic.  I've edited both pieces out.

Comment: OK, then why is it a valid URI? I don't see that "EPSG" is a registered scheme (not in canonical lower case form). Also, while the schema says `anyURI`, that is perhaps not sufficient to be spec compliant (i.e. the spec has other requirements, which valid against the schema is just one).

Comment: Is there a, definition of anyURI, that excludes individual schemes? Syntactical epsg:code could be a URI. There is no rule for upper or lower case letters in rfc3986. The type anyURI for srsName is not Geotools specific. Its defined in OGC
07-036 "OpenGIS® Geography Markup Language (GML) Encoding
Standard" Chapter 10.1.3.2 SRSReferenceGroup.

Comment: It may not be a valid URI, but it is spec compliant if it is recognizable. See [OGC 07-036 GML V3.2.1](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=20509) section 10.1.3.2 : "_In general the attribute srsName points to a CRS instance of gml:AbstractCoordinateReferenceSystem
(see 12.2.3). For well-known references it is not required that the CRS description exists at the location the URI
points to._"

Comment: @AndreasW.Bartels I understand that URI schemes are required to be registered with IANA. I still don't understand the reference to a product - this is about spec compliance, not about interoperability.

Comment: @StevenKalt: Is this a claim that "EPSG:abcd" form "well-known" in a specification sense? That could work. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @BradHards unfortunately, I can't find any references to support that claim.  I have found [a 2013 OGC best practices paper](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=53819) describing adoption of HTTP URIs over URNs, and all OGC standards after a 2010 white paper on http URIs using srsNames in that form. I'm going to edit my answer to use the best practices paper rather than the WFS docs.

Comment: @BradHards: While there's no explicit definition of "well-known" within the GML-3 spec., using OGC 05-029r4's definition of "well-known" as "not requiring resolution," so long as an application can internally identify a CRS from an URI , you might say the CRS is "well-known."    The intent to allow applications to understand shortened srsNames  shows in the spec of aliasing of CRSs via the codeSpace attribute: see the GML-3.2 spec (OGC 07-036) sections 4.1.8 and D.2.7.2.

Comment: @StevenKalt There is a lot of good stuff in the comments. Do you want to try to build a single answer out of this?

Comment: @BradHards: Yes, I'll have that by EOD, after trying to verify if gml:codeSpace obviates srsName resolution.